# How to integrate Google Admob Ads in a MIT App Inventor 2 project?

Tags: android, app-inventor

The MIT App Inventor 2 uses blocks to create the android application, however it does not use Java. I programmed my app in this inventor for a Google Admob student challenge, but now cannot integrate the Admob ads. This will result in my team's disqualification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 12/2017**
use one of the App Inventor distributions, which offer AdMob components
[a list of App Inventor distributions you can find here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ai4a/ajG4Q6UrRR8)

---

This is not available for MIT App Inventor, but there are personal server, which offer this feature:

- AiLiveComplete by Hossein
   **edit**: unfortunately not available anymore, link removed
- AI Personal Server by Jose M. 
   **edit**: unfortunately not available anymore, link removed

Comment: both personal server should be able to read aia files from MIT App Inventor

Comment: I cant buy live complete. But I havent been able to start up the AI Personal Server...
Any advice???

Comment: ask in the [AIliveComplete forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/apptomarket)... and btw. don't forget to accept the answer in case it helped you, [see also how stackoverflow works](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)...

Answer (score 1):

This is not available for MIT App Inventor yet, but you can easily integrate Google Admob Ads in a MIT App Inventor 2 project from [www.thunkable.com](http://thunkable.com)

Step-1: Export your project in .aia file in your local computer.
Step-2: Go to www.thunkable.com and import there .aia file
Step-3: Add AdMob banner or AdMob interstitial from exprimental component.
Step-4: Set ads unit id and go block code and code for the ads load in screen initialize.

You can see the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbO59XV_JBw

Answer (score 1):

I've developed group of extensions that will help you to integrate Admob Sdk in your MIT AI2 applications. Not only, you can integrate bidding with Admob. These extensions are free & open-source at my [Github](https://github.com/oseamiya/AdmobExtension).

Documentation :

https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/free-admob-extension-add-different-types-of-admob-ads-in-your-application/45216?u=oseamiya

Answer (score 0):

You are also can try the https://flipabit.dev as a analog of [www.thunkable.com](http://www.thunkable.com)

Same service but with more powerful possibilities!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.